# Searching JFrog Artifactory API for "Properties" but howto get only the parent folder returned?

Tags: php, curl, artifactory

I am querying our JFrog Artifactory installation for artifacts and my goal is that I want to only get the parent folder returned when querying. Well, maybe it will be better understood after my explanation for what I am doing :-)

Here-and-now I am querying Artifactory via API like this, where I am querying the artifact **Properties** that is inside the `myrepo` repository, where the `SoftwareName` has at least one character and where also the `VersionName` has at least one character:

```
<?PHP
$apiKey = "something";
$apiUrl = "https://mysrv:443/api/search/prop?repos=myrepo&SoftwareName=?*&VersionName=?*";

$ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $artifactoryCertificate);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "X-JFrog-Art-Api: ". $apiKey,
    "Content-Type: application/json")
);
?>
```

This works fine and will return **7905** rows from our setup.
The output will be something like this:

```
Array
    (
        [results] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array (
                    [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/6.2.0.3798
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/6.2.0.4154
                )
                [2] => Array (
                    [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/5.0.5.3876/Documentation
                )
                [3] => Array (
                    [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/5.0.5.3876/Software
                )
                [4] => Array (
                    [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/5.0.5.3876/Documentation/MySoftware1_ChangeLog.pdf
                )
               [5] => Array (
                   [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/5.0.5.3876/Documentation/MySoftware1_ReleaseNotes.pdf
               )
               [6] => Array (
                   [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/6.2.0.4154
               )
               [7] => Array (
                   [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/5.0.5.3876/Documentation
               )
               [8] => Array (
                   [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/5.0.5.3876/Documentation/MySoftware1_ChangeLog.pdf
               )
               ... so on ...
```

As such this is also fine but the problem here is that it return all the child-elements - all the files and their folders but I have no interest in these. The reason it does return the same value for many rows is that our artifacts should inherit its **Properties** on the `MySoftware1` level and below (all versions and files etc.).

The only thing I am interested in is the **parent level** for the version - so that would equal line `[0]`, `[1]` and `[6]` in the above example:

```
Array
    (
        [results] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array (
                    [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/6.2.0.3798
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/6.2.0.4154
                )
               [6] => Array (
                   [uri] => https://mysrv:443/api/storage/My-Component/MySoftware1/6.2.0.4154
               )
```

My practical solution for now is that I still get this resultset of all the **7905** rows and then I process this and divide it in to an array with something like `explode("/",$uri)` and I only look at the first X elements in the array (up to the version number) and then I storing this "one line instead of many" in my database.

Actually of the **7905** rows I really only need **279** rows - so ideally that would be the resultset returned to me :-)

I of course did check the [API documentation](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/artifacts-storage) but was not able to find (or understand) any helpful hints in there.

Is there a better solution for this?